# Why is this finding inverse of a matrix by row operation not working?

Tags: matrices, inverse

[image]

the correct answer is $\begin{pmatrix} -5&3&-6\\-6&3&-7\\-2&1&-2  \end{pmatrix}$

So I think the mistake might be in the first two row operations but I see nothing?

Comment: In the third step, you computed $1 - 3\cdot (-2) = 6$, it ought to be $7$. I didn't look further, so there might be more mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because $1-3\cdot(-2)=7$ and not $6$ in the [$r_3=r_3-3r_2$]-step. If you correct that you'll get $\begin{pmatrix} -5&3&-6\\-6&3&-7\\-2&1&-2  \end{pmatrix}$ as the inverse.